# Why is $SU(n)/SU(n-1)$ the $2n-1$-sphere?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, spheres, fibration, homogeneous-spaces

I am looking at Fomenko, Fuchs' book on "Homotopical Topology" and they claim that we have the isomorphism
$$
SU(n)/SU(n-1) \cong S^{2n-1}
$$
Why is this true? Here is what I have so far:

If I have a matrix $A \in SU(n-1)$, then we can embed $SU(n-1)$ into $SU(n)$ by constructing the block-diagonal matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
From here it is clear that the resulting dimension of the homogenenous space is $2n-1$ since there are $2n-1$ free entries in the matrix from the embedding. I'm not sure though how to use the unitary property of these matrices.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The group $SU(n)$ has a natural action on $\Bbb C^n$ and also
on the unit ball within, the set $\{z\in\Bbb C^n:\|z\|=1\}$
which we can identify with $S^{2n-1}$. Then $SU(n)$ acts transitively
on $S^{2n-1}$. For a suitable point $z_0$ of $S^{2n-1}$ the stabiliser
of $z_0$ is $SU(n-1)$. Therefore we may identify $S^{2n-1}$ with the
coset space $SU(n)/SU(n-1)$.

Comment: Why do we need to only pick one stabilizer?

Comment: @MoarCake559 The stabilizer of *any* point in $S^{2n-1}$ will be isomorphic to $\text{SU}(n-1)$.